# Importing Play Framework module into existing IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I have an IntelliJ project with several modules.  Inside the project directory, I've created a  folder with a Play Framework application in it, and I would like to add this as a module to the existing project.  If I just go to project structure and import module, none of the dependencies are imported.  How do I fix this?

Edit: Sorry, I should have said that I have run `play idea` to get the IntelliJ files.  If I open the folder as a project, it works.  If I try to import it into an existing project as a module, it doesn't add all the dependencies to the Libraries section, and I get red everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modifiy the build file? See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTSubProjects

Comment: hmm... my main project doesn't use SBT.  If I just open the project rather than trying to add it as a module, it has a Scala facet in the project structure.  However, when trying to add a Scala facet to the imported project, the compiler library "SBT: scala:2.10.2" wasn't listed in the drop down, only the maven dependencies were listed.  I'm probably doing something really stupid, but I'm new to SBT and play.

Comment: @stewartml Did you manage to figure this out? I've got the same problem here.

Comment: Long time ago, but I think it was because I had old generated files in target folder. Remove all target folders (and idea folders): do it from a fresh start. Not sure it s the solution to that problem but I remerber that removing these folders helped me a lot